# UrlRewriting not happening

Tags: java, xml, maven, url-rewriting, redirect

I am using `UrlRewriter` for the first time.

Following are the changes I made in my `pom.xml`, `web.xml` and created a new file `UrlRewrite.xml`
Am I missing something?
when I hit the url: http://localhost:8080/myapp/1.0/rest/users from the browser it does not redirect anywhere, instead gives me the result directly.

I checked the library, the `jar` has been downloaded by maven.

**pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

**web.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**UrlRewrite.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>^/myapp/(.*)$</from>
        <to>/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: your set up looks correct , possible cause might be your regex under `<rule>` not matching . Try iterating from a broader rule towards more specific rule.